# Save items from a shopping basket into a php session variable for later use - using an array

Tags: php, sql, session

Firstly, we have a session which runs throughout all of the php webpages.
We also have a sql database were using check boxes we can select items from the database and enter them into a shopping cart. This works.

On the shopping basket webpage we have an array from another page that hold reference numbers to items in our database. we are getting this array by using POST , we have been trying to save this array to our session, as a session variable so it will keep all the reference numbers till the user logs out which will kill the session and also the cart is updated when more items are added at a later date

Below is the table in the shopping basket in php surrounds.

```
   echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Manafacturer</th>";
    echo "<th>Model</th>";
    echo "<th>OS</th>";
    echo "<th>Colour</th>";
    echo "<th>Screen size</th>";
    echo "<th>Price(&pound)</th>";
    echo "<th>Decription</th>";
    echo "<th>Remove</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while ($c = pg_fetch_array($res))
{
if ( isset($_POST[$c['ref']])) {
$newRes = pg_query ($conn, "select * from phones where ref = " . $c['ref'] . "");
 $a = pg_fetch_array ($newRes);
```

The post above needs to be saved into a session variable array list so we can go back to it at a later date

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$a["manufacturer"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$a["model"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$a["os"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$a["colour"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$a["screen"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."&pound".$a["price"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$a["description"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='button' name='".$a["ref"]."' value='Remove'>"."</td>";
```

Comment: Do you also have code putting something in a session?

Comment: we have a simple log in variable which when a user enters a name into a form it is POST'ed' to a session variable and then printed out to all the web pages and this works. I don;t know what you mean exactly